# How to insert data in the database using ajax in laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm working on a simple web application in the laravel framework. I have blade, controller and model files and I want to insert the data into the database with the help of ajax. But, I'm not able to insert the data. Below is the code:

Thanks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#button").on("click", function(){
           var name=$("#name").val();
           var email=$("#email").val();
           $.ajax({
                    url:'insert.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        name:name,
                        email:email,
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
              });
          });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show us the insert.php ? And you should check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing So you can implement the proper way to handle urls in Laravel!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issue with your code:

```
url:'insert.php',  // here you are not working in core php so url is not passed in this way
```

it will be like:

```
url:'{{ url("/insert") }}',  // This 'insert' will be a route and that will be mapped to a controller function.
```

And if you are using:

```
method:'POST',
```

then you have to set the `csrf` token like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

or

```
headers: {
   'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
}
```

Resolve the above issues and try again.

Answer (score 0):

at least, you have to call in your script.

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

Because it is POST request, your csrf_token is required.